# Fetch ingress metadata in kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have below go code that print my kubernetes deployment metadata,

```golang
package test

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "testing"

    v1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func TestEksStandaloneModule(t *testing.T) {
    namespace := fmt.Sprintf("%v-%v", "project", "dit")
    kubeconfig := os.Getenv("HOME") + "/KUBECONFIG"

    clientCfg, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }

    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(clientCfg)

    appDeployment, err := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments(namespace).Get(context.TODO(), "deploymentname", v1.GetOptions{})
    fmt.Println(appDeployment)
}
```

Can any one please help me get a function that prints ingress metadata?
I am new to go.

Comment: Which version of k8s API server are you running? Ingress was in beta before v1.19 and was standardised from that

Comment: networking.k8s.io/v1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work by

```
appIngress, err := clientset.NetworkingV1().Ingresses(namespace).Get(context.TODO(), "helloworldspringbootssl-ap145385", v1.GetOptions{})
fmt.Println(appIngress)
```

Comment: This answer won't work from v1.22 - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122

Comment: Could you help me future proofing it?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/kubernetes/typed/networking/v1#NetworkingV1Client.Ingresses and https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.5/kubernetes/typed/networking/v1#IngressInterface

Comment: I tried clientset.NetworkingV1() and it worked too.
is that good?